# How to re-arrange a list of results?

Tags: list-manipulation

The function mat[v1,vTot] has either one solution or three solution, depending on what vTot is. I want to make a table with pairs of points corresponding to the value of mat and its corresponding vTot. Is there a way to arrange the list on that way? Here is an example of what I get below:

```
p1[x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 2}, {0.6, 4}, {1, 5, 0}, {1.8, 2, 0}, {6, 6}}, x]
p2[x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 0}, {0.25, 2}, {0.6, 4}, {1, 5, 0}, {1.8, 2, 0}, {6, 6}}, x]
en1[v1_] = FullSimplify[Integrate[p1[x], {x, 0, v1}]]; 
en2[v2_] = FullSimplify[Integrate[p2[x], {x, 0, v2}]]; 

enTot[v1_, vTotal_] = en1[v1] + en2[vTotal - v1]; 
vec[v1_, vTotal_] = FullSimplify[D[enTot[v1, vTotal], v1]]; 
mat[v1_, vTotal_] = FullSimplify[D[enTot[v1, vTotal], v1, v1]]; 

solns = v1 /. Table[NSolve[vec[v1, vTotal] == 0 && v1 > 0 && vTotal >= v1, v1, Reals], {vTotal, 0.5, 5, 0.1}]; 
matt = Table[{mat[v1, vTotal] /. NSolve[vec[v1, vTotal] == 0 && v1 > 0 && vTotal >= v1, v1, Reals], vTotal}, {vTotal, 1, 3, 1}]

{{{10.443833014855157}, 1}, {{4.408952530979699, -3.1989511484198374*^-8, 4.408952530959439}, 2}, {{25.671742505141687, -11.865664184452157, 25.671742505076736}, 3}}
```

What I want the result to look like is the following:

```
{{10.443833014855157, 1}, {4.408952530979699,2}, {-3.1989511484198374*^-8,2}, {4.408952530959439,2}, {25.671742505141687,3}, {-11.865664184452157,3}, {25.671742505076736,3}}
```

Comment: `matt = matt /. {lst_List, n_Integer} :> (Sequence @@ ({#, n} & /@ lst))`

Comment: If the last part is a (integer or real) rather than an just integer, change LHS of the rule to `{lst_List, n_?NumericQ}` To get info, highlight the unknown command/function/operator in Mathematica and press `F1` for help. Read the linked documentation.

Comment: Similar to @kglr: `Thread/@matt//Catenate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use composition of [`Splice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html) and [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
spliceThread = Splice @* Thread;
```

to post-process `matt` into the desired form:

```
Map[spliceThread] @ matt
```

> ```
> {{10.4438, 1}, {4.40895, 2}, {-3.19895*10^-8, 2}, {4.40895, 2},  
>  {25.6717, 3}, {-11.8657, 3}, {25.6717, 3}}
> ```

Alternatively, generate the desired list directly using:

```
Table[spliceThread @ 
   {mat[v1, vTotal] /. 
     NSolve[vec[v1, vTotal] == 0 && v1 > 0 && vTotal >= v1, v1, Reals], vTotal}, 
  {vTotal, 1, 3, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{10.4438, 1}, {4.40895, 2}, {-3.19895*10^-8, 2}, {4.40895, 2},  
>  {25.6717, 3}, {-11.8657, 3}, {25.6717, 3}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

step by step:

```
{{4.408952530979699, -3.1989511484198374*^-8, 4.408952530959439}, 2}
```

write a function.

```
f[{x_,y_}] := Map[{#, y}&][x]
```

then Map it

```
{{{10.443833014855157}, 1}, {{4.408952530979699, -3.1989511484198374*^-8, 4.408952530959439}, 2}, {{25.671742505141687, -11.865664184452157, 25.671742505076736}, 3}} //
Map[f] //
Apply[Join]
```

> {{10.443833014855157, 1}, {4.408952530979699, 2}, {-3.1989511484198374*^-8, 2}, {4.408952530959439, 2}, {25.671742505141687, 3}, {-11.865664184452157, 3}, {25.671742505076736, 3}}